# UARTs & Registers

Tags: c, embedded, uart

So I am new to this and trying to learn about registers and UARTs and have been given the following code to study.

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef volatile struct {
    uint32_t DR;
    uint32_t RSR_ECR;
    uint8_t reserved1[0x10];
    const uint32_t FR;
    uint8_t reserved2[0x4];
    uint32_t LPR;
    uint32_t IBRD;
    uint32_t FBRD;
    uint32_t LCR_H;
    uint32_t CR;
    uint32_t IFLS;
    uint32_t IMSC;
    const uint32_t RIS;
    const uint32_t MIS;
    uint32_t ICR;
    uint32_t DMACR;
} pl011_T;

enum {
    RXFE = 0x10,
    TXFF = 0x20,
};

pl011_T * const UART0 = (pl011_T *)0x101f1000;
pl011_T * const UART1 = (pl011_T *)0x101f2000;
pl011_T * const UART2 = (pl011_T *)0x101f3000;

static inline char upperchar(char c) {
    if((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) {
        return c - 'a' + 'A';
    } else {
        return c;
    }
}

static void uart_echo(pl011_T *uart) {
    if ((uart->FR & RXFE) == 0) {
        while(uart->FR & TXFF);
        uart->DR = upperchar(uart->DR);
    }
}

void c_entry() {
    for(;;) {
        uart_echo(UART0);
        uart_echo(UART1);
        uart_echo(UART2);
    }
}
```

I am just wondering if someone could explain how the `pl011` `DR` and `FR` registers transmit and receive data over the associated UART peripheral.
Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: That code is pretty hard to understand without the datasheet of the UART. Take a look at that document, that should explain a lot.

Comment: it would also be very helpful if you could tell us which processor you are using. I only see, that this embeddid MCU has 3 UARTs. pl011_T is that structure, which consists as hardware registers on these three addresses starting with 0x101F1000, 0x101F2000, and 0x10F3000. FR seems to be a Flag-Register, where TX and RX flags RXFE and TXFF are set. DR is the data register for receiving and sending, isn't it? Please tell us which hardware do you use, there are datasheets and manuals for MCUs.....

Comment: What exactly are you not understanding?  Do you get that the DR and FR registers are actually part of the hardware?  The behavior of those registers is defined by the transistors in your hardware.  When the hardware detects you are writing or reading from the addresses associated with those registers, it can do special stuff.  The `typedef` in your code just helps you write to the correct UART register addresses using programmer-friendly names; it doesn't really define registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some nice documentation on this UART here - http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0183g/DDI0183G_uart_pl011_r1p5_trm.pdf

The way this program works is influenced by whether the UART is in `FIFO` mode or not. I have not read enough of the doco to know which is the default state.  The operation of the Tx and Rx differ slightly depending on this mode.  It looks like the code is working only on single words, so *possibly* it's not in FIFO mode (or it doesn't matter for this code).

- `FR` is the UART Flag Register (AKA `UARTFR`).  This contains a bunch of bits that can be queried to see what the state of the UART is.  Two important ones for this question are:

  - `TXFF` is a bit in `FR`, it becomes `1` when the transmit buffer is full.
  - `RXFE` is a bit in `FR`, it becomes `1` when the receive buffer is empty
- `DR` is the UART Data Register (AKA `UARTDR`). This holds the data to be transmitted, and data that has been received.

So Looking at the main working part of the code ~

```
static void uart_echo( pl011_T *uart ) 
{
    if ( ( uart->FR & RXFE ) == 0 )      // While the receive buffer is NOT empty
    {
        while( uart->FR & TXFF );        // Do <nothing> while the Tx buffer is full

        // Read the content of the Data Register, converting it to uppercase(),
        // then make a write to the DR, which initiates a transmit
        uart->DR = upperchar(uart->DR);  
    }
}
```

So this function is echoing back whatever it reads, but in uppercase.  The program is calling this for each of the three UART's, in turn.